# Taking array data from an API and amending a '#' to it to form a hex color

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

A little bit of background about my project - I'm trying to take some information from a color API that I found online and create a color of the day application with it. Basically, it uses React to get a hex value from the API, and then I want to set the background color of my web page to that hex color. The only problem is, the hex value that I receive from the API does not have a '#' in front of it. Since I'm new to JavaScript and React, I'm trying to take the hex code given to me from the API, add a '#' to the beginning of it, and then set that value as my background color. I just am not very sure of the syntax since I'm pretty new to JS. It's not too much code and I'll also include a link to the API I'm using. Any help would be appreciated!

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import "./App.css";

class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      items: [],
      isLoaded: true
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch("http://www.colr.org/json/colors/random/7")
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(res => {
        this.setState({
          isLoaded: true,
          items: res.colors
        });
      });
  }

  render() {
    var { items, isLoaded } = this.state;
    var itemName = items.map(item => (
      <div key={item.id}>{item.tags[0].name}</div>
    ));
    var itemHex = items.map(item => <div key={item.id}>{item.hex}</div>);

    if (!isLoaded) {
      return (
        <div>
          <h1>Not Loaded!</h1>
        </div>
      );
    } else {
      return (
        <section style={{ backgroundColor: { itemHex } }} className="App">
          <h1>today's color of the day is: {itemName}</h1>
          <h2>Hex:{itemHex}</h2>
        </section>
      );
    }
  }
}

export default App;
```

The API I'm using is: http://www.colr.org/json/colors/random/7

Basically, I'm not too sure on how to 1.) append a '#' to the variable 'itemHex' and 2.) properly format the 'style' variable in my `<section>`. If I could get some help with both of these things, that'd be awesome!

Comment: That API gives a lot of different hex colors in an array. Do you want to use one of them as your background color for the entire app, or should each item you render have its corresponding hex color as background color?

Comment: `itemHex` contains an array of `<div>` elements. Why would you want to append '#` to that? Please edit your question to correct the statement in #2 (in your what).

Comment: This made me realize my error. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
colors.forEach(color => color.hex = '#' + color.hex)
```

Result using example provided in your link:

```
0: {timestamp: 1187574525, hex: "#bdd5e0", id: 43679, tags: Array(2)}
1: {timestamp: 1187574417, hex: "#af3f4a", id: 41216, tags: Array(2)}
2: {timestamp: 1187574348, hex: "#a56149", id: 12284, tags: Array(2)}
3: {timestamp: 1187574327, hex: "#a195b3", id: 39159, tags: Array(2)}
4: {timestamp: 0, hex: "#591d35", id: 5464, tags: Array(2)}
5: {timestamp: 1187574615, hex: "#c8d1b8", id: 8433, tags: Array(3)}
6: {timestamp: 1111913319, hex: "#819eca", id: 8406, tags: Array(2)}
```

Comment: For readability sake I would recommend using string literals instead of concatenation. It varies which is faster depending on the browser and version, but the speed difference is mostly too small to matter.